# Call function repeatedly until desired output is received

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm making an automated stat roller of sorts and I want it to keep running until I get the desired output. Here's the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _getStats();
    }

    static void _getStats()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int stat1 = 0;
        int stat2 = 0;
        int stat3 = 0;
        int stat4 = 0;
        int stat5 = 0;
        int stat6 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {

            int roll1 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            int roll2 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            int roll3 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            int roll4 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            int tempStatTotal = 0;
            List<int> rollList = new List<int>();

            rollList.Add(roll1);
            rollList.Add(roll2);
            rollList.Add(roll3);
            rollList.Add(roll4);
            rollList.Sort();
            rollList.RemoveAt(0);

            foreach (int j in rollList)
            {
                tempStatTotal += j;
            }

            if (i == 0)
            {
                stat1 = tempStatTotal;
            }
            else if(i == 1)
            {
                stat2 = tempStatTotal;
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                stat3 = tempStatTotal;
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
                stat4 = tempStatTotal;
            }
            else if (i == 4)
            {
                stat5 = tempStatTotal;
            }
            else
            {
                stat6 = tempStatTotal;
            }
        }

        if(stat1 == 18 || stat2 == 18 || stat3 == 18 || stat4== 18 || stat5 == 18 || stat6 == 18)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(stat1);
            Console.WriteLine(stat2);
            Console.WriteLine(stat3);
            Console.WriteLine(stat4);
            Console.WriteLine(stat5);
            Console.WriteLine(stat6);
        }
        else
        {
            Main(null); //Start the process all over again until one of the stats is 18
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, on a few occasions, the Console logs 6 numbers and 1 of them is 18. Most of the time, the applications breaks and the error `System.StackOverflowException` is thrown. I understand this has something to do with infinite loops and it's happening because I'm recursively calling my method but how do I work around this?

Comment: Don't use recursion, use a do-while loop instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a do-while loop:

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _getStats();
}

static void _getStats()
{
    do
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int stat1 = 0;
        int stat2 = 0;
        int stat3 = 0;
        int stat4 = 0;
        int stat5 = 0;
        int stat6 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {

            int roll1 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            int roll2 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            int roll3 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            int roll4 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            int tempStatTotal = 0;
            List<int> rollList = new List<int>();

            rollList.Add(roll1);
            rollList.Add(roll2);
            rollList.Add(roll3);
            rollList.Add(roll4);
            rollList.Sort();
            rollList.RemoveAt(0);

            foreach (int j in rollList)
            {
                tempStatTotal += j;
            }

            if (i == 0)
            {
                stat1 = tempStatTotal;
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                stat2 = tempStatTotal;
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                stat3 = tempStatTotal;
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
                stat4 = tempStatTotal;
            }
            else if (i == 4)
            {
                stat5 = tempStatTotal;
            }
            else
            {
                stat6 = tempStatTotal;
            }
        }

        if (stat1 == 18 || stat2 == 18 || stat3 == 18 || stat4 == 18 || stat5 == 18 || stat6 == 18)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(stat1);
            Console.WriteLine(stat2);
            Console.WriteLine(stat3);
            Console.WriteLine(stat4);
            Console.WriteLine(stat5);
            Console.WriteLine(stat6);
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Christoph, it works exactly the way I wanted it to now!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, recursion. It's all fun and games until you get a StackOverflowException.

You're correct that your use of recursion is causing this. Recursion is a useful tool, but for it can eat up your memory during long-running operations. As others have already suggested, use a while loop. You could use a do-while loop, but I think a regular one will work just fine.

```
static void _getStats()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int stat1 = 0;
    int stat2 = 0;
    int stat3 = 0;
    int stat4 = 0;
    int stat5 = 0;
    int stat6 = 0;

    while (stat1 < 18 || stat2 < 18 || stat3 < 18 || stat4 < 18 || stat5 < 18 || stat6 < 18)
    {
        // rest of your code
    }

    // Move your printing after the while loop. Once one of the stats hits 18 or above,
    // print the results.
    Console.WriteLine(stat1);
    Console.WriteLine(stat2);
    Console.WriteLine(stat3);
    Console.WriteLine(stat4);
    Console.WriteLine(stat5);
    Console.WriteLine(stat6);
}
```